# Spring Integration Aws: Create Remote Folders Locally

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I am trying to find the configuration for allowing spring-integration-aws to create the remote folder structure locally so it is able to sync.

Example:
Given a very long s3 bucket address:

```
test.s3.bucket/folder1/floder2/folder3/etc/etc/etc/etc
```

Currently get the error message:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.s3.bucket/folder1/floder2/folder3/etc/etc/etc/etc/DD2419D7-104E-46FC-A513-9E587E58A949.ZIP.a.writing (No such file or directory)
```

It looks like it is being caused by not having the full folder structure locally,is it possible to set the `S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` to create this?

Current config:

```
public S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource() {
    S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource =
            new S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(file);
    messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File("onComputer"));
    messageSource.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    return messageSource;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking questions like this, you need to show more of your configuration, including the synchronizer as well as a full stack trace for the exception.

However, no, there is currently not a mechanism to rebuild the remote file tree - it's a simple flat file-only synchronization between the remote directory leaf node and the `localDirectory`.

When `autoCreateLocalDirectory` is true, it's done once, during initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So if I am passed the full quailed name for a zip (for example) with x levels deep, I cannot use this library, as I will not know the full qualified path ahead of time? I was really hoping to use it.

Comment: Also does this mean if you have many files in an s3 bucket it will try and sync everything, I cannot say I want x file?

Comment: While it currently does not provide an [outbound gateway like FTP/SFTP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) the module is built on the same abstractions - so you can use a `S3RemoteFileTemplate` to list, fetch files etc. Also see [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/commit/a0893cb88edb17a376f1ef874d80de98336129ad) which needs some documentation but can be used to download and copy remote directory structures. [Doc JIRA here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-221).